# How do I model a Perl class with "::" in StarUML?

Tags: perl, uml

In StarUML, how can I model a Perl class which uses `::` in its name? It doesn't allow `::` in the class name, reporting:

> Element name cannot contain "::"

Is there a way to work around this limitation?

Comment: You can't. Use [Dia with UML](http://dia-installer.de/shapes/UML/index.html.en) sample and it should give you the best flexibility.